# how to add svg in pdf document iText

Tags: java, svg, itext

I'm using iTextRenderer() to convert html (String) to pdf file. I would like to add on end pdf file, image as svg. I'm using JFreeChart to create SVG File.

```
        File file = new File("D:\\testowy.txt");    //html in string
    File outPDF = new File("D:\\testww.pdf"); //output pdf
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(IOUtils.readUtf(file));

    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outPDF)));
```

Below picture shows how appearance my pdf. The svg file doesnt creat correct.

[image]

The text "7e5a7f..." is a SVG.
I tried use framework PDF, but the text is skip and only svg is created.

```
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(
            new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(outPDF),
                    new WriterProperties().setCompressionLevel(0)));
    doc.addNewPage();
    SvgConverter.drawOnDocument(IOUtils.readUtf(file), doc, 1);
    doc.close();
```

Comment: What version of iText are using? Do you have com.itextpdf/svg as a dependency?

Comment: I used 7.2.5. Now I decided to convert image to png and convert to base64. Thank for it, image is rendered.